# How customize display data in Sonata autocomplete

Tags: symfony, autocomplete, sonata-admin

I use form field **sonata_type_model_autocomplete** and i want customize display. I want to get autocompleteas in the pictures:

[image: autocompletea help image]

[image: autocompletea help data]

Do I understand correctly that the only way to do this is to override the block **sonata_type_model_autocomplete_selection_format** in template **SonataAdminBundle:Form/Type:sonata_type_model_autocomplete.html.twig**? How in [documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-model-autocomplete).
Next I have to create a custom controller that will give me the necessary data and fill **route** option. Perhaps like [this](https://gist.github.com/chalasr/5c27ae64dc596967f18a#file-personneadmincontroller-php).

Is there no a simple and ready-made solution?

Comment: [it seems so impossible](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Controller/HelperController.php#L438)

Comment: I think sonata won't help you much in this particular situation.. The best way to go is, I guess use your own field type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

With option **to_string_callback** can be used, and as a result give not a single field of record, and render template.

```php
class DemoAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $templating = $this->templating;
        $formMapper
            ->add('movie', 'sonata_type_model_autocomplete', [
                'property' => 'title',
                'label' => 'Movie',
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'container_css_class' => 'select2-image',
                'to_string_callback' => function($entity, $property) use ($templating) {
                    return $templating->render(
                        'AcmeDemoBundle:Form/Type/sonata_type_model_autocomplete:movie.html.twig',
                        ['entity' => $entity]
                    );
                },
            ]);
    }
}
```

Template code:

```html
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="select2-image__autocomplete">
        <img
            src="{{ entity.webPath | apply_filter('autocomplete') }}"
            class="select2-image__image"
            alt="{{ entity.title }}"
        />
        <strong>{{ entity.title }}</strong>
        <div>{{ entity.announce }}</div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
```

config.yml

```yml
avalanche_imagine:
    filters:
        autocomplete:
            type: thumbnail
            options: { size: [60, 60], mode: outbound }
```

SCSS

```css
.select2-image {
  height: auto;
  .select2-choice {
    height: 72px; // height 60 + 12 padding
  }
  &__autocomplete {
    clear: both;
    height: 60px;
  }
  &__image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Does this still work? Not able to get `to_string_callback` to render HTML

Comment: @MylesK yes. This still work. https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Form/Type/ModelAutocompleteType.php#L132